# migrating to spring boot 3.0 with external libs running on lower versions

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate to spring boot 3.0 , but i see that in my project there are lot of external libs ( a lot of organisation maintained ) are still on spring boot versions less than 3.0 , my question is, will it be possible to migrate in this scenario.
I see in this blog https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0
that Spring Framework 6.0 will not be binary compatible with the previous generation, does that mean that we can not use spring boot 3.0 or Spring Framework 6.0 when external libs are still running on lower versions.

Comment: That depends on what libriaries we are talking about. Everything depending on Java EE / Jakarta EE APIs (javax.*) will probably going to be a problem.

Comment: As Spring 6 is JakartaEE and Spring 5 is JavaEE it is highly unlikely they are going to be compatible, not to mention the removed classes and changed APIs in Spring 6 compared to Spring 5 (and lower) which aren't going to be compatible as well. Depending on what is being used in those libraries you are possibly looking at a daunting task of shoehorning those in using Spring 6. In short I doubt it will work without any weird compatibility errors.